# Bootstrap 4 header/div positioning

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

### Summary

I'm trying to setup my header so the background is the [particle.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) thingy and then in my header I have a hamburger button and a title that sits in front of the [particle.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) background. I'm new to bootstrap so it's taking some time for me to figure out the order of everything.

### Here's my problem:

[image: broken header with background getting sent below the title/button]

### What I want:

[image: header as I want it]

### Something I've tried

If you can't tell the [particle.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) div is getting pushed below the title/button. If I wrap the title/button in the [particle.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) div then this happens:
[image: something I've tried to fix the header]

### My header code

```
<header class="sticky-top">

    <div id="particles-js">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <button class="hamburger hamburger--spin" type="button">
                    <span class="hamburger-box">
                        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <h1 class="text-center" id="title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>  


</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one of these codes and see which one better sets in your site:

*p* is short for *padding*

*t* is short for *top* (also uou can use other directions, too)

Numbers are available from 1 to 5

Comment: Sorry for my mistake in sending answer. You can use pt-1 until pt-5

Comment: Unfortunately that's not workable. I think the issue revolves around particles.js creating a canvas element after the page loads in which is causing some grief.